# Prestashop 1.7 footer images

Tags: html, css, paypal, prestashop-1.7

Prestashop 1.7 How I could add an image with accepted payments at footer, similar to this page https://www.headict.de also I would like add some animation but I think is very difficult then this is secondary. Anyone could help me, please.

Do I have to modify the code or is possible with the options of prestashop 1.7?

Comment: I am using theme minimal in prestashop.

Comment: It totally depends on your theme. If you have bought the theme just ask the designer.

Comment: It is free theme but the theme doesn’t have support.

Comment: I guess this is the theme: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/334322-free-prestashop-16-17-theme-minimal/ You could ask theme on this topic.

Comment: ok, ready! I hope to find and answer, thanks

Comment: I have not received any answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this free [module](https://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/html-box.html)

Create a new block and place your html.

So, for example, in this new block you can place:

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="Your alt text">
```

After you have created the block, choose design->positions

On the top-right, choose "position a module" and link the block to the footer hook where all the other module blocks in the footer are positioned.

Regards

Comment: The second question.
Do you know what kind of images are used in order to create the animation https://www.headict.de

Comment: well, any kind of image .png or .jpg or .gif or .svg... whatever you want. And headict.de used a .svg. you can see that in the css when you inspect the page

Comment: if you want the same thing, create a DOM element with a class, which has the same properties as their class.

Comment: What program is usually used to create the .svg?

Comment: You could use Photoshop, but just search the web.

Comment: I do not know how to use DOM element.

Comment: A DOM element is a html tag like h1 or div. So in your case, I would place <div class="myimage"></div> and add .myimage to the custom.css file and give it the properties like the other site did using background-image: url(https://m3.headict.com/themes/theme_nq/css/shop/../../img/shop/2/cartes_footer.svg); and replacing the url with your url

Comment: excellent, is it possible to put more content in different positions with html box, seems I only can put one.

Comment: You'd have to read the module documents for this, or you'd have to find a different html box module which can generate multiple boxes.

Comment: I suppose I have to change the module.

Comment: I don't know where I can find the documentation

Comment: Could you help me to change, I don't know what should to change.

Comment: This is a free module and probably has it's limitations. If you want multiple static blocks (in which you can place your code), maybe this module is better suited for your needs. https://addons.prestashop.com/en/blocks-tabs-banners/17343-static-blocks-add-custom-html-text-media-blocks.html. I do want to emphasize that Stackoverflow is a platform for developers // programmers // coders helping out others with code. Prestashop has it's own forum for these sort of questions.

Comment: I can’t afford that, I prefer a free module

Comment: I have already posted a question in the forum of PrestaShop but I have not received any response.